# Tree shaking in angular for not used imports

Tags: angular

How tree shaking works in angular?
Let's assume that I'm building `BigModule` that will handle many kinds of input fields.
That module will have imported modules (to handle different type of input) like module for GoogleMaps, module for date handling and so on. 
In `forRoot` method I'll declare (as `entryComponents`) which fields I want to use in my project.

```
@NgModule({
    imports:[GoogleMapsModule, DateHandlingModule]...
})
export class BigModule {
    static forRoot(config: any): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
          ngModule: BigModule,
          providers: [
            {
              provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
              useValue: config,
              multi: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my project I want to use this BigModule but only few, light components. So I declare them in `forRoot` config.
Will those, not needed, external modules be `shaked off` in build boundle despite of `imports` in module declaration?